# How To Get Value Before Comma In Java Script My Script Attached getting error?

Tags: javascript, html, split

Hi i am getting error in putting value after splitting it to use it in my java script while if i give it value that do not need to split then it runs fine my value that need to be split is

```
option value="intro.wmv,1"
```

when i give it simple intro .wmv value and just get it in script accordingly then it run fine  while in the above condition it gives me error ??
    my script is shown below it works on click that is,

```
function PlayIt(){
var s = "'+document.getElementById('cancion').value+'";
var str_array = s.split(',');
document.getElementById("music1").innerHTML='<object id="mediaPlayer" width="470" height="400" '
+'classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" '
+'codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701" '
+'standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject">'
+'<param name="fileName" value="'+str_array[0].value+'">'
+'<param name="animationatStart" value="true">'
+'<param name="transparentatStart" value="true">'
+'<param name="autoStart" value="1">'
+'<param name="showControls" value="true">'
+'<param name="loop" value="true">'
+'<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">'
+'<param name="ShowPositionControls" value="true">'
+'<param name="enableContextMenu" value="1" />'
+'<param name="fullScreen" value="0" />'
+'<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" '
+'pluginspage="http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/" '
+'bgcolor="darkblue" showcontrols="true" showpositioncontrols="true" showstatusbar="true" showgotobar="true" width="470" height="400" '
+'src="'+str_array[0].value+'" autostart="true" designtimesp="5311" loop="true">'
+'</embed>'
+'</object>'
}
```

hopes for your reply

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The value of variable s wont give the expected option value.

Try changing it to
`var s = "'"+ document.getElementById('cancion').value + "'";`

No need to use `str_array[0].value` . Try simple `str_array[0]`. This should eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Access the elements of array by using **str_array[0]** instead of **str_array[0].value**

Comment: i did it but it results in error then i use str_array[0].value :(

Comment: can you do an alert like this alert(str_array);

Comment: it is not giving any thing on alert :(

Comment: what is "'+document.getElementById('cancion').value+'";  To be more specific what is cancion? Is it a div which has that String value?

Comment: cassion is a selet id in which we have option value that we have to split

Comment: var s = document.getElementById('cancion').value;
var str_array = s.split(',');  Try this and then see the value using str_array[0]

Answer (score 0):

Your `s` variable doesn´t seem to contain any comma `,`.

`var s = "'+document.getElementById('cancion').value+'";`

Use `console.log(s, s.split(','));` to view the output.

I´m assuming you´re trying to access the value of a `select` element so try the following;

```
var select = document.getElementById('cancion');
var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
var valueBeforeComma = selectedValue.split(',')[0];
```